# How to subsetting rows group wise in R?

Tags: r, loops, subset

Probably my question title is not appropriate, sorry for that. I have a csv file named "table_parameter". [Please, download from here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY3OAw62EShd2xnRjB0Z055bUU/view?usp=sharing). Data look like this:

```
           time      Avg.PM10       sill      range       nugget
1   1   2012030101  52.269231   0.11054330  45574.072   0.037261216
2   2   2012030102  55.314286   0.20250974  87306.391   0.048315377
3   3   2012030103  56.038095   0.17711558  56806.827   0.034956709
4   4   2012030104  55.904762   0.16466350  104767.669  0.030752835
5   5   2012030105  57.123810   0.23638953  87306.391   0.037308364
6   6   2012030106  58.542857   0.24130317  87306.391   0.042108754
7   7   2012030107  60.066667   0.20362439  87306.391   0.037353980
8   8   2012030108  63.790476   0.19417801  87306.391   0.034144464
.
.
.
```

In my dataframe there is a variable named `time` contains hours value from 01 march 2012 to 7 march 2012 in numeric form. for example 01 march 2012, 1.00 a.m. is written as 2012030101 and so on.

I want to subset this dataframe time wise. I want a dataframe contains only morning times of every 7 days. morning time is 1.00 am to 5.00 a.m. That means I want a dataframe which contais all the value belongs to 2012030101 to 2012030105, 2012030201 to 2012030205..........2012030701 to 2012030705.in other words,I want a dataframe like below:

```
              time      Avg.PM10      sill       range        nugget
1   49  49  2012030301  17.371429   0.7154449   48239.54    0.17163448
2   50  50  2012030302  17.811321   1.1201199   117603.55   0.12425337
3   51  51  2012030303  17.094340   0.5799705   55103.16    0.12061258
4   52  52  2012030304  16.679245   0.8486774   86725.77    0.15210005
5   53  53  2012030305  16.885714   1.2408621   154677.61   0.09743375
6   73  73  2012030401  21.619048   0.4417369   104767.67   0.08567888
7   74  74  2012030402  20.485714   2.0271124   215474.54   0.06340464
8   75  75  2012030403  20.552381   0.4509354   104767.67   0.06319812
9   76  76  2012030404  20.104762   0.4438798   104767.67   0.05639840
10  77  77  2012030405  20.133333   0.5050201   104767.67   0.09037341
.
.
.
```

For doing this I wrote these code:

```
table<-read.csv("table_parameter.csv")
table
table_morning<-subset(table, time %in% c(2012030101:2012030105,
                                         2012030201:2012030205,
                                         2012030301:2012030305,
                                         2012030401:2012030405,
                                         2012030501:2012030505,
                                         2012030601:2012030605,
                                         2012030701:2012030705) & Avg.PM10 <=30)
table_morning
```

But this code is not efficient.as you see, I wrote all the hour values to subset! If want to do the same work for 90 days then Its very inefficient. So, how can I do this subsetting efficiently? If you have any further query please let me know.

Comment: You could create a new variable 'hours' in your dataset (as your time variables are numeric, you could try time %/% 100). Then subset based on that.

Answer (score 1):

you could use substring like below:

```
table_morning <- subset(table, substring(time, 9, 10) %in% c("01", "02","03","04", "05") & Avg.PM10 <=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the hour from the time and then filter accordingly.
For example:

```
library(dplyr) 
data_orpheus = read.csv('table_parameter.csv') 
data_orpheus$hour = as.numeric(substr(as.character(data_orpheus$time),9,10))
data_morning = data_orpheus %>% filter(hour >= 1 & hour <= 5)
```

The `dplyr` operator `%>%` is not necessary, you could filter with `data_morning = data_orpheus[with(data_orpheus,hour >= 1 & hour <= 5)]`

#### Update

I am still learning `dplyr`, so here is a beautiful one-liner that does it all:

```
data_morning = read.csv('table_parameter.csv') %>%     # Read CSV
    mutate(hours = as.numeric(substr(time,9,10))) %>%  # Extract hours
    filter(hours >= 1 & hours <= 5) %>%                # Keep only mornings
    select(-hours)                                     # Drop hours, if not needed

head(data_morning)
   X       time Avg.PM10      sill     range     nugget
1  1 2012030101 52.26923 0.1105433  45574.07 0.03726122
2  2 2012030102 55.31429 0.2025097  87306.39 0.04831538
3  3 2012030103 56.03810 0.1771156  56806.83 0.03495671
4  4 2012030104 55.90476 0.1646635 104767.67 0.03075283
5  5 2012030105 57.12381 0.2363895  87306.39 0.03730836
6 25 2012030201 67.10476 0.1434977  72755.33 0.03003781
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for Other answers. My improvised answer for my future advantage:

```
table<-read.csv("table_parameter.csv")
times<- as.numeric(substr(table$time,9,10))
table_morning<- subset(table, times>=1 & times<=5 & Avg.PM10<=30)
```